# copy shipping address to billing address using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i want to copy shipping address to billing address,
but problem is when i select India as country and state as Gujarat then in billing state the first state is displayed.

here is my code :

Shipping Country :

```
<select class="form-control shippingCountry valid" id="shipping_country" name="shipping_country" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">American Samoa</option>
<option value="5">Andorra</option>
<option value="6">Angola</option>
```

Shipping State:

```
<select class="form-control shippingState" id="shipping_state" name="shipping_state">
<option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
<option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="4">Assam</option>
<option value="5">Bihar</option>
<option value="6">Chandigarh</option>
```

Billing Country :

```
<select class="form-control billingCountry" id="billing_country" name="billing_country">
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">American Samoa</option>
<option value="5">Andorra</option>
<option value="6">Angola</option>
```

Billing State:

```
<select class="form-control billingCountry" id="billing_state" name="billing_state">
<option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
<option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="4">Assam</option>
<option value="5">Bihar</option>
<option value="6">Chandigarh</option>
```

JQuery :

```
$("#copyAdrs").change(function ()
{
    if ($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        $('#billing_street').val($('#shipping_street').val());
        $('#billing_city').val($('#shipping_city').val());
        $("#billing_country").val($('#shipping_country').val()).change();
        $("#billing_state").val($('#shipping_state').val()).change();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are those select values already present in `billingstate`? Post the `html` code instead of `php`.

Comment: while copying values get the values from country and select state, similar with city

Comment: Please click the `<>` and post a [mcve] - no need for PHP code at all. Show RENDERED HTML and a running jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

It makes more sense.

```js
$("#copyAdrs").on("click",function () {
  var cpy = this.checked;
  $.each(["street","city","country","state"],function(_,item) {
    $('#billing_'+item).val(cpy?$('#shipping_'+item).val():"");
  });
});
```